# What does cz mean?

Tags: star

Take DS Geminorum for example, it has a cz of -2.33 [2.96]

My question is what does cz mean, what does is represent? and what does the value in the brackets mean?

http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=ds%20gem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It stands for the speed of light ($c$) times the redshift ($z$) as measured from the redshift of the spectrum.
It is equal to the line-of-sight velocity that the star has. Positive means going away from us.
It is given in a heliocentric reference frame, that is corrected for the rotation of the Earth around its axis/the Sun.

The -2.33 is the velocity (km/s) and the [2.96] is its uncertainty.

Comment: $cz$ is the line of sight velocity, **if** $z \ll 1$.

Comment: Normally it holds for individual stars. See comment above for cosmological scale.